# Una possibile eccezione al "se + congiuntivo" nel periodo ipotetico

Tags: grammar, conditional-mood

Il periodo ipotetico della possibilità esprime una certa relazione causale tra due fatti, due eventi, due "stati di cose": se si verifica il primo (protasi), è più o meno probabile che si verifichi anche il secondo (apodosi).
Nella grammatica italiana, la protasi di questo periodo ipotetico deve contenere un verbo al congiuntivo, mentre l'apodosi un verbo al condizionale.

Ma qui ho trovato un potenziale problema. Ogni frase descrive uno stato di cose, e il periodo ipotetico non fa eccezione: come ho già detto, descrive una relazione causale tra due eventi, che è essa stessa uno stato di cose. Ma cosa succede se l'evento descritto dalla protasi di un periodo ipotetico è *un altro periodo ipotetico*?

**Mi spiego meglio con un esempio.** Prendete la frase *"se uscissi di casa durante il coprifuoco sarei multato"*. Fin qui nulla di controverso. La frase rappresenta una certa regola, chiamiamola "regola X". Ora considerate la frase *"se vigesse la regola X non uscirei di casa durante il coprifuoco"*. Anche qui nulla di strano. Ma cosa succede se sostituiamo la regola X con il suo contenuto? Otterremmo qualcosa come *"**se sarei** multato (qualora uscissi di casa durante il coprifuoco) non uscirei di casa durante il coprifuoco"*. Naturalmente questa frase va evitata nello scritto perché non è molto elegante, ma nel parlato mi sembra decisamente naturale, perché il parlante segue spontaneamente la regola "se è vero che [fatto 1] allora è vero [fatto 2]". In genere cercherà di descrivere il 'fatto 1' (la protasi) coniugando il verbo al congiuntivo, e il 'fatto 2' coniugando il verbo al condizionale, ma ci sono casi in cui questa regola è in contrasto con se stessa, come ho appena mostrato. Penso che buona parte dei parlanti inizierebbe a dire "se sarei..." ma poi si accorgerebbe della stonatura e si correggerebbe. Ma se la frase suona male è solo perché siamo condizionati ad accoppiare sempre "se" e congiuntivo in un periodo ipotetico, e in effetti è così nel 99,9% dei casi pratici.

Io credo che una persona attenta alla lingua non dovrebbe correggere chi parla in questo modo. Ho ragione? Mi piacerebbe sentire il parere degli esperti di questo forum.

EDIT: @secan mi ha fatto notare che ho invertito il significato di protasi e apodosi. Adesso è corretto, ma nei miei commenti sotto restano invertite (almeno l'uso è coerente).

Comment: Onestamente fatico a seguire il tuo ragionamento né capisco per quale motivo tu ritanga possa essere corretto "_se **sarei** multato, non uscirei di casa durante il coprifuoco_" anziché "_se **fossi** multato, non uscirei di casa durante il coprifuoco_"

Comment: Inoltre ritengo non corretta l'affermazione secondo cui il periodo ipotetico descriverebbe una relazione _causale_ tra due eventi. Ad esempio, nella frase "se fossi veloce potrei acchiappare le mosche al volo" l'essere veloce rappresenta una _condizione neccessaria_ perché io possa acchiappare le mosche al volo, non la _causa_ per cui lo farei.

Comment: Nella frase "se fossi multato ..." è implicita la premessa "se uscissi di casa durante il coprifuoco", ma non puoi dire "se fossi multato (qualora uscissi di casa durante il coprifuoco), ..." perché il periodo ipotetico vuole il condizionale nella protasi. Per capire meglio la struttura della frase, considera la frase *"se è vero che sarei multato se uscissi di casa, non uscirei di casa"*. Non puoi dire \**se è vero che fossi multato se uscissi di casa, ...*.

Comment: Hai ragione, ma non è una condizione necessaria, bensì sufficiente. Per semplificare ho detto relazione causale, mi sembra l'aggettivo che più ci si avvicinava.

Comment: A mio avviso, la sostituzione che applichi nel tuo ragionamento è totalmente arbitraria e scorretta dal punto di vista grammaticale, perché confonde una corrispondenza logica (tra "la regola X" ed il suo contenuto) con una corrispondenza grammaticale. Un conto è l'equivalenza del significato, un altro quello della forma: semplicemente, non si può prendere un periodo ipotetico ed usarlo, così com'è, senza alcuna variazione, per sostituire un sostantivo.

Comment: @secan il punto è proprio che non è semplice adattare la forma ma preservare il significato. Il periodo ipotetico è "se + <frase1>, allora + <frase2>". Se la <frase1> è anch'essa un periodo ipotetico (del resto, chi me lo vieta?), abbiamo il problema che ho descritto.

Comment: Capisco il problema, e trovo che l'esempio del “sarei multato” lo esasperi particolarmente, per motivi che non riesco a mettere a fuoco: credo che c'entri il verbo al passivo. Riformulando la frase con un verbo attivo e altre modifiche, mi sembra che il congiuntivo suoni bene: “Se mi multassero se esco di casa, non uscirei”. (Ma forse funziona anche “Se venissi multato se esco di casa, non uscirei”.)

Comment: Fuori tema: (A→B)→C è rognoso, al contrario di A→(B→C), che è equivalente a (A∧B)→C.

Comment: @DaG Forse hai ragione: in questo caso il periodo ipotetico principale ha la precedenza sul periodo ipotetico secondario, nel senso che la prima apodosi forza il congiutivo, anche se contiene una costruzione che normalmente richiede il condizionale. Quindi avremmo naturalmente un'altra eccezione: la protasi di un periodo ipotetico non vuole il condizionale quando è parte di un'altra apodosi. È meno scandalosa della prima solo perché sbagliare il condizionale è molto meno stigmatizzato (e molto meno diffuso) che sbagliare il congiuntivo.

Comment: Secondo me la forzatura sta nel fatto che il periodo è formulato in modo da _sembrare_ la concatenazione di due periodi ipotetici, "Se fossi multato (protasi A / aposodi B) se uscissi di casa durante il coprifuoco (protasi B) non usicirei di casa (apodosi A)", [...continua...]

Comment: [...] quando in realtà il nesso tra "essere multato" ed "uscire di casa durante il coprifuoco" è di tipo causale quindi la struttura sarebbe "Se fossi multato (proposizione condizionale A / protasi A / reggente B) se [_per il motivo che_] uscissi [_esco_] di casa durante il coprifuoco (proposizione causale B) non usicirei di casa (reggente A / apodosi A)". Pertanto, al limite, il congiuntivo su cui si può discutere è il secondo, non il primo